# Warning sign/exclamation point in red circle next to table names and Query tab?

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel, whm

I have a VPS with CENTOS 6.4 and WHM 11.38.2. I just updated WHM to the latest version, and now when I go to phpMyAdmin there are red circles with white exclamation points in them next to the table names and before the word "Query" in the Query tab.

The warning signs are kind of stupid, because there's no message when I hover over them and they aren't clickable. Searching the web and on here for these warning signs didn't produce any results.

What do these warning signs mean, and what should I do to fix whatever issue exists?

UPDATE:

I've been messing around with phpMyAdmin and there's definitely something wrong. When I click on a database name, the tables no longer show in the left pane.

Comment: try updating phpmyadmin and see if it works

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first description sounds like you have stale icons in your cache. You can solve that by clearing your web browser cache.

About your second problem (after "UPDATE:"), what phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: Just wanted to add, it is the *browser* cache we are talking about. It didn't look obvious to me ;) (I thought of some phpmyadmin / server cache)

Comment: Just had the same issue, the related cached file with the icons was phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/sprites.png.

Answer (score 0):

About the second problem:

**Re-run create-tables.sql**

```
sudo updatedb
locate create-tables.sql
```

Located at /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/create_tables.sql.gz for me.

```
cd ~
cp /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/create_tables.sql.gz .
gunzip create_tables.sql.gz
```

Run the resulting create_tables.sql (just through phpmyadmin is fine).

**Check phpmyadmin access**

Check the phpmyadmin config file: /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php (on ubuntu) for the database password.
Make sure the phpmyadmin user in mysql has the right password, and all rights on the phpmyadmin database.

**Log out and back in to phpmyadmin, and the problem should be fixed**