# PHPMYADMIN yellow triangle signs

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a windows user working with XAMPP to benefit from PHP and MySQL.
I uninstalled XAMPP, restarted and reinstalled XAMPP to start using wordpress yet as soon as I entered phpmyadmin there are yellow triangles containing an exclamation mark before database names. The tooltip reads as "Database Operations".
I am very new to MySQL and don't know how to fix the issue. Would you guid me throught the process of fixing it?

Comment: Read the phpmyadmin manual, maybe?

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211323/warning-sign-exclamation-point-in-red-circle-next-to-table-names-and-query-tab

Try clearing your cache (Hard refresh: Ctrl-F5 in most browsers).

Comment: Dear Dan, clearing browser cash worked  perfectly. Thank you very much.